# this keyword inside anonymous function/constructor

Tags: javascript

To some extent I know whats happening in the code,just to clear my doubts I have posted this question

JavaScript

```
Point = function (x, y)     //Here anonymous constructor is define 
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var points=[] 
points.push(new Point(centerX + radius * Math.sin(angle),centerY - radius * Math.cos(angle)));  //object is created and push in the array
```

And to access the value of points array,I can write points[i].x?

Comment: Yes, precisely. The `this` keyword is simply a self-reference. If you add `console.log(points)` to your JavaScript, you can see the structure of your objects to get a better understanding of what's going on under the hood.

Comment: "I can write points[i].x" - How about testing?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the constructor function is anonymous. It would have been good practise to use `function Point(x, y) {…}` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check this

```
   var Point = function (x, y)     //Here anonymous constructor is define
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var points = [];
points.push(new Point(2,5));
points.push(new Point(3,11));
points.push(new Point(9,1));

for(var i = 0; i <points.length; i++){
console.log(points[i].x);
console.log(points[i].y);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you can access the object using its index i, and then you are dereferencing the object to access it's attribute/member

```
var Point = function (x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var points = [];
points.push(new Point(1, 2));
var point = points[0];
alert(point.x == point[0].x);
```